# Reasons why my mouse is not showing up in my wordpress site after uploading the header and footer with a plugin?

Tags: wordpress, plugins, mouseevent

We are designing a WP site from a template called Remake, and, after uploading the final versions of the header and footer through a plug in, the mouse (cursor) suddenly disappeared! Can't find an issue inside the code, when we remove the plug in, the cursor appears and thats the only way to fix it BUT we need to use it. (It's happening with any plug in we use...)

Comment: Can you provide a bit of code ? Did you tried removing header, then footer, and see if the problem is still here ?

Comment: add_action( 'codeless_hook_viewport_after', 'codeless_add_mouse_cursor' );
function codeless_add_mouse_cursor(){
    $request_uri = '';
    if( function_exists( 'codeless_request_uri' ) )
        $request_uri = codeless_request_uri();

    if( !codeless_get_mod( 'mouse_cursor', true ) || strpos($request_uri, 'elementor') !== true )
        return;
    ?>
    <!-- The cursor elements --> 
    <div class="circle-cursor circle-cursor--inner"></div>
 <div class="circle-cursor circle-cursor--outer"></div>
    <?php
}

Comment: Would this portion help? And yes, we've tried removing both the footer and header but the problem remains.

Comment: You're talking about a plugin that create this issue. Can you tell us the name of it ?

Comment: Yes, the name of the plugin is Elementor Header & Footer Builder
By Brainstorm Force, Nikhil Chavan.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.